# Using MySQL Like to search for a number with symbols

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a number in a column (a `varchar` column) using `LIKE`, I am using a statement like this `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE mynumberslist LIKE '%76%'`. The data is stored like this: nums=;76;78;80;81;176; So how do I go about searching for 76 because if I just do `LIKE %76%` I will get 76 and 176 returned is there anyway around this? I did not design the database, and have no control over the data that is stored, I am only responsible for writing a program that gets the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex matching:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE mynumberslist RLIKE '\b76\b'
```

This will match even if you don't have a trailing `;` at the end - it matched the *word* 76 (`\b` means "word boundary" in regex)

Comment: In case when leading and trailing semicolons are not guaranteed - it is also possible to use `CONCAT` to add them just to avoid using regexes

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as just

```
LIKE '%;76;%'
```

ps: send hello to the database schema author and donate him some money to buy any DB-design-related book

Comment: +1 I have to admit... your answer is better than mine :) [KISS Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_it_simple_stupid)

Comment: I tried that but I never get any results returned when I use the semi colons in my select statement

Comment: @atrljoe: if you gave us the correct data sample `nums=;76;78;80;81;176;` - then it should work. If it doesn't - then you need to correct the question with **actual** data so we could fix the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MYTABLE 
 WHERE ';' + mynumberslist + ';' LIKE '%;76;%';
```